# how to manage Django urls alias redirections?

Tags: django, redirect, django-urls

I'd like set up my urls correctly avoiding doing it like the example below since it afects my Google indexation :

**urls.py (wrong way) :**

```
url(r'^virtual-reality/$', views.virtualreality, name="virtual-reality"),
url(r'^virtual-reality$', views.virtualreality, name="virtual-reality"),
url(r'^vr/$', views.virtualreality, name="virtual-reality"),
url(r'^vr$', views.virtualreality, name="virtual-reality"),
```

As you can see I'd like `vr/`, `vr`, `virtual-reality/`, `virtual-reality` to redirect to the same page. I have more than 30 urls on my site and doing each url redirection like this is problematic since the structure grows.

I do not use Apache on my Django site, so Rewriting Rules can not be made. (I'm on pythonanywhere (webserver : Gunicorn))

What's the best way to redirect all types of aliases in the same view without affecting my google search indexation and avoid to enter each url with the same view to urls.py ?

Comment: Note that you can leave out the urls without a slash at the end and use [`APPEND_SLASH`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#append-slash) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way to do it is using django redirect app https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/redirects/ you can easily manage redirects from the admin with this.

Comment: is there any order for the middleware since I just tried it and it doesn't work when I try the redirection through the admin panel ex : '/vr/' to '/virtual-reality/'

Comment: I am using that as my first middleware and it works just fine. Just be aware of the APPEND_SLASH setting.

Comment: Best solution so far

Answer (score 2):

Another way to solve the trailing slash problem, is to use `?` flag in the regex.

```
url(r'^virtual-reality/?$', views.virtualreality, name="virtual-reality"),
url(r'^vr/?$', views.virtualreality, name="virtual-reality"),
```

If using CommonMiddleware, it adds the trailing slash and return the view with it (if the version without the trailing slash is not found in any urlpattern). It can be seen in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/#django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware).

Answer (score 1):

### `urls.py` is Python after all

Just write a suitable data structure that can capture what you want
and use a loop to generate the list containing the `url()` calls from that.